# PHP input form to ajax request json

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a file search.php where I get the input from the form and I create an url. I want the data(url_api) to pass it to an AJAX script, where I can request an json. How can I pass the variable api_url to ajax data ?

Here is my code:

```
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit')){

$area=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'm', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



// The access url is created with data from the form
$api_url = "http://wwww/api/v1/wwww?";

if ($m !== "") {
    $api_url = $api_url . "m=" . $m;
}



$api_url = $api_url . "&api_key=wxaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
```

And the ajax script

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'search.php', //This is the current doc
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'jsonp', // add json datatype to get json
    data: ?,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try like : `exit(json_encode($api_url));`

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php to make your code a bit more clear

Comment: you want to pass the the php variable "$api_url" as data in ajax ! Am i right ??

Comment: Yes  @VamsiKrishna I want the variable to pass and with that to make a json request

Comment: You can define a js variable in php like this.
<script>var api_url = '<?php echo $api_url; ?>'</script>
Then you can use this js variable 'api_url' in your ajax like data: {'url':api_url}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'search.php', //target PHP script
    type: 'POST', //data will be send with POST method
    dataType: 'json', //data will be sent as JSON
    data: { //data sent to PHP script
        key1: 'val1', //keys / values
        key2: 'val2'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //get the url sent back by PHP and do whatever you want with it
        console.log(data.url);
    }
});
```

In your PHP script:

```
//get data post by Ajax as POST parameters
$key1Val = $_POST['key1']; // === 'val1'
$key2Val = $_POST['key2']; // === 'val2'

//build your $url

//send back built URL to your JS script as JSON
echo json_encode([
    'url' => $url
]);
```